# Finding a substring in a file and selecting to the index of another matched string .NET (Any Language), batch, powershell, java, Objective-C

Tags: java, .net, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to edit a file where I need to find a pattern match and redact to the occurrence of another matched pattern.

For Example:

string s = 'This Text; This text has a pattern=XXXXXX; This text has a 2nd pattern=XXXXXX;'

What I need is

s.substring(s.indexOf('pattern='), s.indexOf(';'))

However I need that second index which looks for ';' needs to be the occurence after the indexOf the pattern that was matched before it.

So my contexts would be XXXXXX

Just to throw this out there the XXXXXX has a variable length. Also There will be multiple occurrences of the pattern and I need to retrieve all of them.

Comment: pick a language and google on how to parse text for that chosen language

Comment: The issue was not the language, or how to parse text. It is the method in which you identify a matched patterned index after the occurrence of a first matched index. All languages can do string manipulation, I just needed assistance with the theory behind pattern matching when using multiple patterns and etc. nevertheless I figured out the quickest way to retrieve the variable contents that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split with the string "pattern=", discard the first substring and in the remain substrings just look for ";"?

By example, your sample text would look like:

```
This Text; This text has a
XXXXXX; This text has a 2nd
XXXXXX;
```

So in 2nd and 3rd substring just look for the first ";" or even you can split again but now using the ";" as separator.

Comment: Because of the multiple occurrences of the indexes. That would require a loop to hit each section I need to edit if I understand you properly.

Answer (score 0):

I used powershell as a quick way to get the code out, but will eventually convert to C# and include in my app, but I figured it out like so...

```
$fileContents = Get-Content $file -Raw

$startIndex = $fileContents.IndexOf('pattern=') + 8
$endIndex = $fileContents.substring($firstIndex).IndexOf(';')

(Get-Content $file).Replace($fileContents.Substring($startIndex, $endIndex), '[###REDACTED###]') | Set-Content $file
```